# Databricks cli - dbfs commands to copy files

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-purview

I'm working on the [Deployment of the Purview ADB Lineage Solution Accelerator](https://github.com/microsoft/purview-adb-lineage-solution-accelerator/blob/main/deploy-base.md). In step 3 of [Install OpenLineage on Your Databricks Cluster](https://github.com/microsoft/purview-adb-lineage-solution-accelerator/blob/main/deploy-base.md#install-openlineage-on-your-databricks-cluster) section, the author is asking to run the following in the`powershell` to Upload the `init` script and `jar` to [dbfs](https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/index.html) using the [Databricks CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/).

```
dbfs mkdirs dbfs:/databricks/openlineage
dbfs cp --overwrite ./openlineage-spark-*.jar               dbfs:/databricks/openlineage/
dbfs cp --overwrite ./open-lineage-init-script.sh           dbfs:/databricks/openlineage/open-lineage-init-script.sh
```

**Question**: Do I correctly understand the above code as follows? If that is not the case, before running the code, I would like to know what exactly the code is doing.

1. The first line creates a folder `openlineage` in the root directory of `dbfs`
2. It's assumed that you are running the `powershell` command from the location where `.jar` and `open-lineage-init-script.sh` are located
3. The second and third lines of the code are copying the `jar` and `.sh` files from your local directory to the `dbfs:/databricks/openlineage/` in `dbfs` of Databricks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`dbfs mkdirs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli#create-a-directory) is an equivalent of UNIX `mkdir -p`, ie. under DBFS root it will create a folder named `databricks`, and inside it another folder named `openlineage` - and will not complain if these directories already exist.
2. and 3. Yes. Files/directories not prefixed with `dbfs:/` mean your local filesystem. Note that you can copy from DBFS to local or vice versa, or between two DBFS locations. Just not between local filesystem only.